# Error invalid type argument of '->' (have 'tree')

Tags: c, pointers

i tryin to insert node in my tree, but i got the error

> invalid type argument of

```
#define info(p) (p)->info
#define left(p) (p)->left     //error here
#define right(p) (p)->right   // and here
#define root(t) (t).root
#define infoRoot(t) ((t).root)->info
#define nil NULL

typedef struct treenode *data;
typedef struct treenode {
    int info;
    data right;
    data left;
}node;
typedef struct{
    data root;
}tree;
```

when i try to use this procedure :

```
void insert(tree *T,int x){
    //Kamus
    data baru;
    data bantu;

    //Algoritma
    baru = (data)malloc(sizeof(node));
    left(baru) = right(baru) = nil;
    info(baru) = x;

    bantu = root(*T);
    if(isEmpty(*T)){
        root(*T) = baru;
    }
    else if(bantu == nil){
        baru = bantu;
    }
    else{
        if(x < info(bantu)){
            bantu = left(bantu);
            insert(&left(*T),x);  
        }
        else{
            bantu = right(bantu);
            insert(&right(*T),x);
        }
    }
}
```

When i use code like that in list, it can be compiled, hat am I doing wrong with the pointer ?

Comment: Why are you using macros - does not really improve the code.

Comment: Why would you do this?!? How is this making your code anything other than more difficult to read!

Comment: It would help if you gave the full error and the line(s) where it occurs (and you didn't use those macros), but after a quick skim, you're passing `*T` (a `tree`) into the `left()` and `right()` macros which appear to expect a pointer to a `node`.

Comment: I think by using macros help our code that is easy to use.
When i compile, the red line is #define left(p) (p)->left

Comment: For a start using macros you are already looking at the wrong place. Those `#define`s are fine.

Comment: okay, I understand , it is better not to use macros. But i do not have any idea about the error that happen. I'm still learning

Comment: lol 'I think by using macros help our code that is easy to use'. Please unthink.

Comment: And do not `typedef` pointers. Obfuscates the semantics (i.e. makes your code less readable) and is error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

Running the preprocessor on this code with `gcc -E` shows the substitutions made that may make these errors a little more clear.

```
void insert(tree *T,int x){

    data baru;
    data bantu;


    baru = (data)malloc(sizeof(node));
    (baru)->left = (baru)->right = ((void *)0);
    (baru)->info = x;

    bantu = (*T).root;
    if(isEmpty(*T)){
        (*T).root = baru;
    }
    else if(bantu == ((void *)0)){
        baru = bantu;
    }
    else{
        if(x < (bantu)->info){
            bantu = (bantu)->left;
            insert(&(*T)->left,x);
        }
        else{
            bantu = (bantu)->right;
            insert(&(*T)->right,x);
        }
    }
}
```

If `T` is of type "pointer to a tree" then `(*T)` is of type "tree".  So `(*T)->left` does not work because the `->` operator attempts to dereference `(*T)` which is not a pointer!

There may be other errors in here but this should get you on your way to a fix.  Hopefully you can see how this use of macros obscures your code and in this case your code would be more readable and less error prone if you used the `->` and `.` operators in the body of your code instead of via the preprocessor in `#define` directives.